# Android NDK no implementation found

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

```
W/dalvikvm(3937): No implementation found for native Lcom/video/v2/camera/ExternalCamera;.converttobmp (Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)V
```

to load library in `public class ExternalCamera` used

```
static {
            try {
                System.loadLibrary("ExternalFullHd");
            } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
    }   
public native void converttobmp(Bitmap bitmap);
```

in ExternalFullHd.c & ExternalFullHd.h i have

```
void Java_com_video_v2_camera_ExternalCamera_stopCamera(JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz);
void Java_com_video_v2_camera_ExternalCamera_converttobmp ( JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz,jobject bitmap);
```

&

```
void 
Java_com_video_v2_camera_ExternalCamera_converttobmp( JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz,jobject bitmap){
//code

}
```

Comment: Is `converttobmp()` actually implemented in `ExternalFullHd.c` or is it just copying the prototype from the header file with no code block?

Comment: You're catching the UnsatisfiedLinkError but not actually logging a failure.  Change "e.getMessage" to something that throws to make sure the library is getting loaded.  dlopen() failures *should* be getting logged by the VM, so make sure you're watching the log as your app is starting.

Comment: Charles, yes it's implemented, i edited with my question

Comment: Can you post the native function declaration in java?

Comment: `public native void converttobmp(Bitmap bitmap);`

Comment: Hey, are you using a C compiler or a C++ compiler? In the latter case, declare the prototype/implementation (in C++) as "extern C", to avoid compiler mangling. Also, you should add a JNIEXPORT in the declaration of the C/C++ function.

Comment: i use GNU C in eclipse, Am i right that if i state `System.loadLibrary("ExternalFullHd");` i do not need `JNIEXPORT`?

Comment: @dividebyzero: in the Java code, no, but in the C/C++ code it is recommended. Is the implementation of the .stopCamera() function found?

Comment: yeah, all is present and done like this for all the functions. 
Can it be that files are compiled in a wrong way by compiler and code is fine?

Comment: @dividebyzero: if the headers/paths are correctly declared, then only two possibilities remain: 1) the dynamic linker does not found the generated .so file (does it have it on the path?) or 2) the .so file is not generated at all. Check that manually. And print the exception message that you catch.

Comment: @axeoth, the extern C helped me. You can write this and i will accept your answer, big thanks, after i faced the problem now i better understand the "native" setup and some basics :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, do not forget to declare your C/C++ functions as `extern "C"` and JNIEXPORT.